# Replace numpy matrix elements with submatrices

Tags: python, performance, numpy, indexing, vectorization

Given that I have a square matrix of indices, such as:

```
idxs = np.array([[1, 1],
                 [0, 1]])
```

and an array of square matrices of the same size as each other (not necessarily the same size as `idxs`):

```
mats = array([[[ 0. ,  0. ],
               [ 0. ,  0.5]],

              [[ 1. ,  0.3],
               [ 1. ,  1. ]]])
```

I'd like to replace each index in `idxs` with the corresponding matrix in `mats`, to obtain:

```
array([[ 1. ,  0.3,  1. ,  0.3],
       [ 1. ,  1. ,  1. ,  1. ],
       [ 0. ,  0. ,  1. ,  0.3],
       [ 0. ,  0.5,  1. ,  1. ]])
```

`mats[idxs]` gives me a nested version of this:

```
array([[[[ 1. ,  0.3],
         [ 1. ,  1. ]],

        [[ 1. ,  0.3],
         [ 1. ,  1. ]]],


       [[[ 0. ,  0. ],
         [ 0. ,  0.5]],

        [[ 1. ,  0.3],
         [ 1. ,  1. ]]]])
```

and so I tried using `reshape`, but 'twas in vain! `mats[idxs].reshape(4,4)` returns:

```
array([[ 1. ,  0.3,  1. ,  1. ],
       [ 1. ,  0.3,  1. ,  1. ],
       [ 0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0.5],
       [ 1. ,  0.3,  1. ,  1. ]])
```

If it helps, I found that `skimage.util.view_as_blocks` is the exact inverse of what I need (it can convert my desired result into the nested, `mats[idxs]` form).

Is there a (hopefully very) fast way to do this? For the application, my `mats` will still have just a few small matrices, but my `idxs` will be a square matrix of up to order 2^15, in which case I'll be replacing over a million indices to create a new matrix of order 2^16.

Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Oops! Yes it should - thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We are indexing into the first axis of the input array with those indices. To get the `2D` output, we just need to permute axes and reshape afterwards. Thus, an approach would be with `np.transpose`/[`np.swapaxes`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.swapaxes.html) and [`np.reshape`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html), like so -

```
mats[idxs].swapaxes(1,2).reshape(-1,mats.shape[-1]*idxs.shape[-1])
```

Sample run -

```
In [83]: mats
Out[83]: 
array([[[1, 1],
        [7, 1]],

       [[6, 6],
        [5, 8]],

       [[7, 1],
        [6, 0]],

       [[2, 7],
        [0, 4]]])

In [84]: idxs
Out[84]: 
array([[2, 3],
       [0, 3],
       [1, 2]])

In [85]: mats[idxs].swapaxes(1,2).reshape(-1,mats.shape[-1]*idxs.shape[-1])
Out[85]: 
array([[7, 1, 2, 7],
       [6, 0, 0, 4],
       [1, 1, 2, 7],
       [7, 1, 0, 4],
       [6, 6, 7, 1],
       [5, 8, 6, 0]])
```

---

**Performance boost with [`np.take`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.take.html) for repeated indices**

With repeated indices, for performance we are better off using `np.take` by indexing along `axis=0`. Let's list out both these approaches and time it with `idxs` having many repeated indices.

Function definitions -

```
def simply_indexing_based(mats, idxs):
    ncols = mats.shape[-1]*idxs.shape[-1]
    return mats[idxs].swapaxes(1,2).reshape(-1,ncols)

def take_based(mats, idxs):np.take(mats,idxs,axis=0)
    ncols = mats.shape[-1]*idxs.shape[-1]
    return np.take(mats,idxs,axis=0).swapaxes(1,2).reshape(-1,ncols)
```

Runtime test -

```
In [156]: mats = np.random.randint(0,9,(10,2,2))

In [157]: idxs = np.random.randint(0,10,(1000,1000))
                 # This ensures many repeated indices

In [158]: out1 = simply_indexing_based(mats, idxs)

In [159]: out2 = take_based(mats, idxs)

In [160]: np.allclose(out1, out2)
Out[160]: True

In [161]: %timeit simply_indexing_based(mats, idxs)
10 loops, best of 3: 41.2 ms per loop

In [162]: %timeit take_based(mats, idxs)
10 loops, best of 3: 27.3 ms per loop
```

Thus, we are seeing an overall improvement of **`1.5x+`**.

Just to get a sense of the improvement with `np.take`, let's time the indexing part alone -

```
In [168]: %timeit mats[idxs]
10 loops, best of 3: 22.8 ms per loop

In [169]: %timeit np.take(mats,idxs,axis=0)
100 loops, best of 3: 8.88 ms per loop
```

For those datasizes, its **`2.5x+`**. Not bad!

Comment: Thank you so much! This works perfectly - I'll keep `swapaxes` in mind for future reference.

Comment: @JubJub Added an improvement with `np.take`. Check it out!

Comment: oh my gosh thank you so much! This helps immensely:D